# C++ Use the class type as the value of the map

Tags: c++, stdmap

```cpp
class Animal {
 public:
  virtual std::string Say() = 0;
};

class Mouse : public Animal {
 public:
  std::string Say() { return "I am a mouse."; }
};

class Duck : public Animal {
 public:
  std::string Say() { return "I am a duck."; }
};

class Dog : public Animal {
 public:
  std::string Say() { return "I am a dog."; }
};

class Zoo {
 public:
  void Build(std::map<std::string, ClassType> animals) {
    for (std::map<std::string, ClassType>::iterator it = animals.begin(); it != animals.end(); it++) {
      this->animals[it->first] = new it->second();
    }
  }

 private:
  std::map<std::string, Animal*> animals;
};

int main() {
  Zoo zoo;
  zoo.Build({{"Mickey", Mouse}, {"Daisy", Duck}, {"Goofy", Dog}});

  return 0;
}
```

It is hoped that the **class type** can be passed in as the **value of the map** when calling zoo.Build().

And use this class type inside Build, ex: **new Class()**;

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass class types around. You need to create instances of something. That something could be an instance of a class template, where the template parameter is the type of animal you'd like to instantiate:

```cpp
template<class T>
struct am {};     // animal maker
```

In this, you could also store the arguments you need (if any) to instantiate the correct animal and also the *Key* value that you need in the `map`. You can also add an implicit conversion *from* such an instance to the `map`'s *value_type* (`std::pair<const Key, T>`).

```cpp
template<class T>
struct am {
    std::string_view name;

    // implicit conversion to the map's value_type:
    operator auto () && {
        return std::pair<const std::string, std::unique_ptr<Animal>>{
            name, std::make_unique<T>()};
    }
};
```

Your `Zoo` could then be:

```cpp
class Zoo {
public:
    template<class... Args>
    void Build(Args&&... args) {
        // fold over the comma operator:
        (..., animals.emplace(std::forward<Args>(args)));
    }

private:
    std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Animal>> animals;
};
```

and used like so:

```cpp
Zoo zoo;
zoo.Build(am<Mouse>{"Mickey"}, am<Duck>{"Daisy"}, am<Dog>{"Goofy"});
```

Note: Your base class, `Animal`, needs a `virtual` destructor to be able to `delete` animals via the base class pointers:

```cpp
class Animal {
public:
    virtual ~Animal() = default;   // add this
    virtual std::string Say() = 0;
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7ffqE8TGb)

Comment: May I ask the purpose of && in operator auto () && of struct am, thanks again!

Comment: @wilson.liu It's an rvalue reference-qualifier. It means that the function will only available when `*this` is an rvalue. The effect is that the implicit conversion is "turned off" if you try this: `am<Mouse> a{"Mickey"}; am<Duck> b{"Daisy"}; am<Dog> c{"Goofy"}; zoo.Build(a, b, c);`.  If you _do_ want the implicit conversion even in that case, remove the ref-qualifier.

Answer (score 2):

C++ classes are types, and you can't pass types as arguments or create "type" objects. You need to use some kind of [*builder pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) to solve your problem.

For example you could could have a (fluent) builder-class like this:

```
class ZooBuilder;  // Forward declaration

class Zoo
{
    friend ZooBuilder;

public:
    // Public interface of the Zoo class...

private:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Animal>> animals_;
};


class ZooBuilder
{
public:
    ZooBuilder(Zoo& zoo)
        : zoo_{ zoo }
    {
    }

    template<typename animalT>
    ZooBuilder& add(std::string const& name)
    {
        zoo_.animals_[name] = std::make_unique<animalT>();
        return *this;
    }

private:
    Zoo& zoo_;
};
```

You can then use it like:

```
Zoo my_zoo;

ZooBuilder(my_zoo)
    .add<Mouse>("Mickey")
    .add<Duck>("Daisy")
    .add<Dog>("Goofy");
```

---

In my example I have created a separate builder class, but you can put the `add` function template into the `Zoo` class itself, to make the `Zoo` class its own builder.

Comment: A note about the missing `virtual ~Animal() = default;` would probably save OP from some future troubles too.